How to fix some games not running in Ubuntu 24.04?
I am a new user of Ubuntu 24.04 for personal use. I want play a game on Ubuntu and I also tried to install kapman and ksudoku, but these games are not starting.
I installed PlayOnLinux, but it is also not working...

I answered the game part of the question. Playonlinux seems to be a totally different issue. Please ask a new question about it and edit it out from the current question.

Yes, I am using Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop

You may have installed the snap versions of these games (in case you are using the app store), which may have issues.
Switching to the apt version will most likely help.
First, remove the snap apps. Open a terminal, and run the following commands one by one.
sudo snap remove kapman
sudo snap remove ksudoku

Now run the following command to install these apps with APT.
sudo apt install ksudoku kapman

Now they should work when you open the apps from the app menu.

Thanks frnd it's working can you suggest me any hindi typing tutor application

What do you mean by typing tutor? For typing Hindi you can use ibus-m17

If it is working, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of the answer
